# How to send files with my Application

Tags: android

I am a newbie :).

How can I do as my Application to appear in the list of applications when I am trying to send a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

use this for send images